# How to cut 4 lines of text from a string variable which has html tags in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having a string variable with html tags, like below

```
புதுடெல்லி:<br><br>
இந்தய வணிக வாகன தயாரிப்பு நிறுவனமான ஈச்சர் மோட்டார்ஸ் இந்தியாவில் எலெக்ட்ரிக் பேருந்துகளை அறிமுகம் செய்ய திட்டமிட்டுள்ளது. <br><br>
நகரப்புறங்களுக்கு ஏற்ற எலெக்ட்ரிக் பேருந்தை ஈச்சர் மோட்டார்ஸ் தயாரித்து வருவதாக வி.இ. மோட்டார்ஸ் நிறுவனத்தின் இலகு மற்றும் கனரக வாகன பிரிவு துணை தலைவர் ஷியாம் மல்லர் சமீபத்திய பேட்டியில் தெரிவித்தார். மேலும் புதிய எலெக்ட்ரிக் பேருந்து தயாரிப்பு பணிகளில் உள்ளதாகவும் விரைவில் இதற்கான அறிவிப்பு வெளியாகும் என கூறப்படுகிறது.<br><br>
ஈச்சர் மோட்டார்ஸ் மற்றும் வால்வோ டிரக் நிறுவனங்கள் இணைந்து வி.இ. வணிக வாகனங்கள் துவங்கப்பட்டுள்ளது. இந்த நிறுவனம் தொழில்நுட்பங்களை பகிர்ந்து கொண்டு வாகனங்களை தயாரிக்கும் பணிகளில் ஈடுபடுகின்றன. எலெக்ட்ரிக் வாகனங்களின் திட்டங்களின் படி ஈச்சர் மோட்டார்ஸ் நிறுவனத்திட்ம உள்ளது, வால்வோ உடனான கூட்டணிக்கு நன்றி என மல்லர் தெரிவித்தார்.<br><br><img src="" alt="" width="615" height="350"><br><br>
```

How can i cut 4 lines of text from this.can anyone help for me

Comment: What problem are you having ?

Comment: I can't find any raw html method in typescript.so that i can't easily split it by newline character

Comment: can you pls guide me to use raw html method in typescript

Comment: not sure what you mean by raw html method ... and the string you posted does not contain any html tags.

Comment: I posted with tags,.But it is chaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For raw text, you can split based on newline characters. For the specific HTML in your question, you could split based on the tags. This is reasonably fragile, especially if you consider line break tags can be `<br>` or `<br />`, for example.

```
const text = `புதுடெல்லி:<br><br>
இந்தய வணிக வாகன தயாரிப்பு நிறுவனமான ஈச்சர் மோட்டார்ஸ் இந்தியாவில் எலெக்ட்ரிக் பேருந்துகளை அறிமுகம் செய்ய திட்டமிட்டுள்ளது. <br><br>
நகரப்புறங்களுக்கு ஏற்ற எலெக்ட்ரிக் பேருந்தை ஈச்சர் மோட்டார்ஸ் தயாரித்து வருவதாக வி.இ. மோட்டார்ஸ் நிறுவனத்தின் இலகு மற்றும் கனரக வாகன பிரிவு துணை தலைவர் ஷியாம் மல்லர் சமீபத்திய பேட்டியில் தெரிவித்தார். மேலும் புதிய எலெக்ட்ரிக் பேருந்து தயாரிப்பு பணிகளில் உள்ளதாகவும் விரைவில் இதற்கான அறிவிப்பு வெளியாகும் என கூறப்படுகிறது.<br><br>
ஈச்சர் மோட்டார்ஸ் மற்றும் வால்வோ டிரக் நிறுவனங்கள் இணைந்து வி.இ. வணிக வாகனங்கள் துவங்கப்பட்டுள்ளது. இந்த நிறுவனம் தொழில்நுட்பங்களை பகிர்ந்து கொண்டு வாகனங்களை தயாரிக்கும் பணிகளில் ஈடுபடுகின்றன. எலெக்ட்ரிக் வாகனங்களின் திட்டங்களின் படி ஈச்சர் மோட்டார்ஸ் நிறுவனத்திட்ம உள்ளது, வால்வோ உடனான கூட்டணிக்கு நன்றி என மல்லர் தெரிவித்தார்.<br><br><img src="" alt="" width="615" height="350"><br><br>`;

const lines = text.split('<br><br>');

for (const line of lines) {
    if (line.match(/\S/)) {
        alert(line);
    }
}
```

The more advances/robust method would be to load the HTML chunk into an HTML parser.

Comment: But it has more lines of text for each <br><br>.I should have only one line of text.how can i acheive this

Comment: @kamalav I have added a condition to ignore empty entries